# How to solve the ImportError: cannot import name simplejson in Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-1.7, simplejson

I'm trying to build a realtime chat app in Django(1.7.1). It seems that I needed to install Redis and ishout.js. So I installed them by following the instructions.

After making the project in Django, I put 'drealtime' under the INSTALLED_APPS, and put:

```
'drealtime.middleware.iShoutCookieMiddleware'
```

right above :

```
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'
```

under the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` as it was saying. And I put the command like

```
python manage.py startapp example
```

but still I have this import error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/drealtime/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.utils import simplejson as json
```

After I searched through the Django official site, I found simplejson is no longer used and removed from new Django. I don't know why this is happening. 
Please give any feedback on this issue and possible remedy to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of `django-realtime`.

Upgrade it to the latest version, they [fixed the 1.7 compatibility](https://github.com/anishmenon/django-realtime/commit/e7223aeb60c27a5a571e6c7f9d7703d280826b70):

```
pip install django-realtime --upgrade
```

If the error persists, install directly from github, master branch:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/anishmenon/django-realtime.git --upgrade
```

FYI, the fix:

```
try:
    from django.utils import simplejson as json
except:
    import simplejson as json
```

<sup>Bare exception clause - zen programmer inside is killing me whispering `except ImportError`, `except ImportError`, [except..](https://github.com/anishmenon/django-realtime/pull/7)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any view.py file yet because when I tried to make the application, this error popped up, not allowing me to have any view.py file. The __init__.py file is empty for now.

Comment: @SungpahLee nono, I mean update the `django-realtime` package, reinstall it to the latest version: `pip install django-realtime --upgrade`.

Comment: rescomp-14-285794:realpro sungpah$ pip install django-realtime --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: django-realtime in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
rescomp-14-285794:realpro sungpah$

Comment: @SungpahLee see the updated answer please (install from github).

Comment: And still I have a same problem when trying to make an app. When I installed django-realtime, the command was like "pip install django-realtime"

Comment: Awesome. Now the app is installed!!!!!!Thanks so much. I was bogged down to this issue for 6 hours..

Comment: 1+ for try..except section, really helpful

Answer (score 5):

I think the above answers are workarounds.

Django used to ship with **simplejson** in **django.utils**, but this was removed in [Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.5/#django-utils-simplejson) because **json** module being available in Python’s standard library.

So you should now `import json` instead of `from django.utils import simplejson`, and make necessary changes where simplejson methods are called.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the application itself; unfortunately [the error still persists in the master branch](https://github.com/anishmenon/django-realtime/blob/master/drealtime/__init__.py) at git.

I submitted a pull request to fix the error; in the meanwhile you can do the following:

```
pip uninstall django-realtime
pip install git+https://github.com/burhan/django-realtime.git@import-fix
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for a really great advice on this issue and hope that the generic problem would be solved quickly