# ImportError: cannot import name simplejson. I am using django v1.8 and django-Select2 v4.3.1

Tags: python, django

My error( command python manage.py runserver) - **File "/Users/username/virtual-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonfield/fields.py", line 3, in 
    from django.utils import simplejson as json
ImportError: cannot import name simplejson**

I tried solutions from these two posts but they did not work in my case [Cannot import name simplejson - After installing simplejson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048943/cannot-import-name-simplejson-after-installing-simplejson)
[How to solve the ImportError: cannot import name simplejson in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855731/how-to-solve-the-importerror-cannot-import-name-simplejson-in-django)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If this error was in your own code, then you would simply change

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json
```

to

```
import json
```

after upgrading to Django 1.5 or later.

However, in your case, it looks like the problem is that you've have an old version of [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) installed. If you upgrade to the latest version (currently 1.03), it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Use `import json as simplejson` instead

As of django 1.5, `simplejson` is no longer in `django.utils` module. So, just use python's JSON module instead.